# Emulate a captured portal in Android

Tags: android

I want to test how my application handles captured portals, ie portals like public access points where it requires you to log in before it stops redirecting all your requests,
 is there any way to emulate this in either emulator, or code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958614/how-to-check-for-unrestricted-internet-access-captive-portal-detection) link. You can use Google to generate a response that you like.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to detect if I am in one, i want to test my detection by emulating being IN one