# How to detect when the user is connected to public wifi BUT not approved wifi term of use

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity, networkinfo

My app needs to work on workplaces/airports that have a free public wifi network.

I would like to inform the user when he need to approve the wifi term of use through a web browser.

I tried to extract information, But didn't find any attribute / info to isolate this case

```
public static void haveNetworkConnection(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            Toast.makeText(mContext, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            printWifiInformation(activeNetwork);
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            Toast.makeText(mContext, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public static void printWifiInformation(NetworkInfo activeNetwork){

    System.out.println("************************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("1 . describeContents         " + activeNetwork.describeContents());
    System.out.println("2 . getDetailedState         " + activeNetwork.getDetailedState());
    System.out.println("3 . getExtraInfo             " + activeNetwork.getExtraInfo());
    System.out.println("4 . getReason                " + activeNetwork.getReason());
    System.out.println("5 . getState                 " + activeNetwork.getState());
    System.out.println("6 . getSubtype               " + activeNetwork.getSubtype());
    System.out.println("7 . getSubtypeName           " + activeNetwork.getSubtypeName());
    System.out.println("8 . getSubtypeName           " + activeNetwork.getSubtypeName());
    System.out.println("9 . getType                  " + activeNetwork.getType());
    System.out.println("10. getTypeName              " + activeNetwork.getTypeName());
    System.out.println("11. isAvailable              " + activeNetwork.isAvailable());
    System.out.println("12. isConnected              " + activeNetwork.isConnected());
    System.out.println("13. isConnectedOrConnecting  " + activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    System.out.println("14. isFailover               " + activeNetwork.isFailover());
    System.out.println("15. isRoaming                " + activeNetwork.isRoaming());
    System.out.println("************************************************************************************");

}
```

I got the same result when I checked before and after clicking the web browser.
Please advise,
Thanks,
Luther

Comment: You could try to "ping" this server and if it is now connected, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by doing a connectivity check to verify that you are inside a **Captive Portal** *walled garden*.

There is a pretty good explanation of that [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030276/2819928).

Still, this does not give you info on the captive portal itself.

So you will have to manually handle the `HttpUrlConnection` response headers and look for a redirect

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     if (!url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost())) {

      // we were redirected! Kick the user out to the browser to sign on?
     }
     ...
   } finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

The official documentation is generous enough to provide a series of [examples](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) which include Handling Network Sign-On, Http Authentication as well as handling cookies. You should give it a look.
Hope this helps!